# how do you put a string into a specific spot in an array based on a number in java?

Tags: java, arrays

How would I put a string into an array in a specific spot based on a number?

```
public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String studentNumber, int grade){
    courseTimeTable = new String[] {"Block " + courseBlock + ": " + course, "Block " + courseBlock + ": " + course};
}

public void setCourse(int block, String courseCode) {
    course = courseCode;
    courseBlock = block;
}
```

So how would I put the "course" into the "courseTimeTable" array based on the "courseBlock"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to know the maximum size of courseTimeTable first.

Then you can do:

```
 courseTimeTable = new String[<maximumSize>];
 courseTimeTable[courseBlock] = ...;
```